# Adding custom fields to User class without extending GrailsUser

Tags: grails, spring-security, custom-fields

I'm using spring security and want to add to my user class custom fields. As I understood, the only way to do it is to extend GrailsUser, but I can't do that, because my class has to extend another domain class.
This is my user class:

```
    class User extends BasicDomain {
    transient springSecurityService;
     .....
    }
```

I want to add a field, does somebody have any idea hoe to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google following property

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName
```

You can define it in config.groovy like following

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.company.security.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.company.security.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.company.security.Role'
```

And create your own tagLib

```
import com.company.security.User

class SecurityTagLib {
    def springSecurityService

    static namespace = "mySec"

    def nickName = { attrs ->
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser as User
        out << "${user.nickName}"
    }

}
```

Comment: I did it already,and my class is recognized, but without the fields I added. When I try to get them I get an error.

Comment: This is the code which get the fields : ${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:"")}.
This code is ok, because it's a built-in field: ${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:"username")} ,
but the next line causes an error, because it's a field I added:
${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:"someField")}
This is the error: Caused by MissingPropertyException: No such property: nickName for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser

Comment: Yes it is looking to "org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser" calss.
YOu can create your tag lib something like following 


import com.yourCompany.security.User

class SecurityTagLib {
    def springSecurityService

    static namespace = "mySec"

    def nickName = { attrs ->
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser as User
        out << "${user.nickName}"
    }

}

Comment: could you please write it as an answer, so I can see the code clearly? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try it & let you know if it worked.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand how to use the taglib class.

Answer (score 0):

I can't decide if this an elegant solution or a complete bad-idea hack, but it's working for me.

If you look at the SecurityTagLib source, it has a little bit of code that I'm interpreting to mean "if we're dealing with a UserDetails object, use the domain class (what you set as your grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName) instead to get the value of the field.

Except that the test to see if we're using the default UserDetails is "does it have a method called getDomainClass?"   And the current implementation does not.

My solution is to give it one in BootStrap.groovy.  My domain class for the user object is called User and the username is unique:

```
GrailsUser.metaClass.getDomainClass = { ->
  User.withTransaction { status ->
    return User.findByUsername(delegate.username)
  }
}
```